# Conditionally copy and paste a range within a loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a sales tool to quickly mark companies as qualified or disqualified using check boxes in google apps script. Users can manually check a box for "qualified", "unqualified", or "Not Sure". If an "unqualified", or "not sure" box is checked, the row will be hidden and and the "not sure" rows will be copied and pasted into a new sheet called "Maybes". I have built an auto qualify function that will automatically check the qualify or disqualify box based certain terms that it reads from column E. Sometimes the macro will check both boxes (both qualifying and disqualifying terms present). When that happens, I have written this macro to automatically check the not sure box and then paste that row into the "Maybes" tab. To do this I have created a loop to check that both boxes are checked, check the "not sure" box (this part works perfectly), and then copy and paste the row into the new tab. The problem I am running into is that only the very last row ends up getting copied. When I run the debugger it will copy whatever row I exit at (i.e. when step over i = 5 and then I hit stop, it will copy and paste that row. But when I let the whole function run it will only copy and paste i = 1000). It seems like the loop does not want to paste all the values, instead it only wants to paste the last one run. All help is appreciated!

```
function auto_maybes(){
var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Maybes");
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Qualification 1");
var Qual_range = source.getDataRange().getValues();
 
for( var i = 1; i< Qual_range.length; i++){
if(Qual_range[i][0] == true && Qual_range[i][1] == true){
    var maybe_range = source.getRange(1+i,3);    
    maybe_range.setValue("TRUE");
    var maybe = maybe_range.getRow();
    var info = source.getRange(maybe,4,1,7);
    info.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true} );
}
}
}
'''


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzpzc.png
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it this way

Since you used getDataRange() is hard to be sure but normally there is at least one header in a spreadsheet.  So I start my data at row 2.  But perhaps you can correct me if I'm wrong.

```
function auto_maybes() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName("Maybes");
  const qsh = ss.getSheetByName("Qualification 1");
  const qvs = qsh.getRange(2,1,qsh.getLastRow() - 1, qsh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  qvs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[0] == true && r[1] == true) {
      qsh.getRange(i + 2,3).setValue("TRUE");
      qsh.getRange(i + 2, 4, 1, 7).copyTo(msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow() + 1 ,1))
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely works. You say it was the getDataRange() that was making it not work? I haven't played around with the forEach function yet but apart from yours being cleaner, our conditional loops are very similar and yours actually copy and pasted for each i where the conditions were met where mine only pasted the last instance

Comment: Well getDataRange() is similar to sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()) and generally speak we tend to expect at least one row of column titles.  I must admit that I don't tend to look for fault in scripts once I figure out what is being attempted I normally move to a method that I would deploy.  If you are not familiar with array methods I would recommend learning them because they really can empower your code to do more with less code.

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot of experience coding spreadsheet macros in VBA so I am very familiar with spreadsheet arrays but this is my first adventure into G Apps Script. After playing around with it more it really seems that the route of the problem is the for vs forEach method. When I tested your same code with for instead of foreach i was running into the same problem. Headers are not relevant in my dataset which is why i started at row 1 and I always want to check to understand why my original code didn't work so I can learn from it. Anyway thank you so much for the help! All the best